# EC25 GPS auto initialize

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, embedded, gps

I am using EC25 with embedded board using ubuntu.
When board start working EC25 doesnt response from ttyUSB1. But if I write

```
AT+QGPS=1
```

at `ttyUSB3`, I can get response(location,speed etc.) from `ttyUSB1`.
How can I make this automatically when device power on?
I'm trying with *gtkterm*.
I tried different thing but didnt make it.
I'm running python on board and I have crontab file for auto start my python code.
I would like to know a command line or settings for fixing my problem.

- I already tried to `AT+QGPSCFG=“autogps”` and `AT+QGPSCFG=“autogps”[,<autogps>]` but it given error "gne error: 501(device user manuel)
- I tried to `AT+QGPSAUTOSTART=1` (I dont remember where I saw this command) but its given "error"

Problem Solved!
First
`AT+QGPS=1`
return OK
then
`AT+QGPSCFG="autogps",1`
return OK
for checking the command;
`AT+QGPSCFG="autogps"`
return autogps, 1

Comment: Did you copy&paste the command exactly as you used it? You should learn to understand the syntax description in the manual. `<autogps>` is a placeholder which has to be replaced with `0` or `1` as explained in the manual. `[` and `]` mark optional parts. The typographical quotes in `“autogps”` are probably wrong. Try `"autogps"` instead. I guess you typed the error message instead of copying&pasting it as requested. The manual specifies `+CME ERROR: <errcode>` not `gne error:` Please always **copy&paste** code, commands and messages.

Comment: Please add (copy&paste) all the "different things" you already tried and tell us how it failed to avoid that we propose the same things or to allow us to find possible mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a search engine with keywords "EC25 GPS" I found a support forum https://forums.quectel.com/t/ec25-do-not-get-gps-position-from-gnss-module-after-reboot/9353

> To make GPS automatically run after power on, please refer to command AT+QGPSCFG=“autogps” of the attached document.

The page contains a download link to the manual.

> 2.1.9. AT+QGPSCFG=“autogps”[,<autogps>] Enable/Disable GNSS to Run Automatically

I guess you might have to use normal (typewriter) quotes instead of typographical quotes.

Note that `<autogps>` is a placeholder which has to be replaced with `0` or `1` according to the manual. `[` and `]` mark optional parts. Correct command might be

```
AT+QGPSCFG="autogps",1
AT+QGPSCFG="autogps",0
AT+QGPSCFG="autogps"
```

Comment: I already tried this but response: gne error 501, i will try again

Comment: @AhmetAçıksarı If you already tried this, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76507384/edit) and *copy&paste* what exactly you tried and the exact error response. Don't re-type it because this could introduce or remove errors.